# Single Sliding Window in Spark Structured Streaming

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, spark-structured-streaming

I am trying to implement a system which is measuring something based on data from last `n` hours. Here is the simple example:
I am constantly getting new messages with the following format: `{"temp": <temp>, createdAt: <timestamp>}`. I want to calculate the average temperature for last `1 hour`, so if at this moment the time is `15:10` I want to consider only those records, which have `createdAt` field set to time after `14:10`. Others should be dropped.

Is there anyway I could do it gently in spark structured streaming and keep with only one window? I was looking at sliding windows feature but that would result in multiple windows, which I don't really need.

Answer (score 0):

> I was looking at sliding windows feature but that would result in multiple windows, which I don't really need.

If you don't want overlapping windows, then what you are looking for is a **Tumbling** window. From the code perspective, you use the same syntax as for *Sliding* window, but you leave the `slideDuration` param to its default `None`.

PySpark docs on this topic - https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.3/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.window.html#pyspark-sql-functions-window